# How can I merge and transpose the data into a single record?

Tags: filemaker

How can I merge the links for matching inventory ID's into a single record? There are 30 image fields (Image 1, Image 2, Image 3 etc.). The number of links for each INV ID varies item to item. Each link should be in the corresponding image field relative to it's position/count. Goal is to be able to export the inventory IDs with all of their corresponding links as a single CSV line item. I know it's possible with a looping/verify/set field script but there must be a better way.

I have tried a looping set field by name script. My struggle was referencing the first record reliably. I am sure I could do this through some sort of looping find, exit on error script but it just felt wrong.

[Layout Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHlE5.png)

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

> Goal is to be able to export the inventory IDs with all of their corresponding links as a single CSV line item.

A calculation field (result is Text) =

```
List ( Image 1 ; Image 2 ; Image 3 ; ... Image 30 )
```

will contain a return-separated list of all values from non-empty `Image X` fields.

In a .csv export this field will be a single cell, with the returns replaced by the vertical tab character (I don't know why Filemaker does this). If you want another delimiter, then wrap the calc in `Substitute()` - e.g. =

```
Substitute ( List ( Image 1 ; Image 2 ; Image 3 ; ... Image 30 ) ; ¶ ; "," )
```

---

As a side note, this is really a very poor structure to have. Consider moving the image links to a child table with an individual record for each.